# What is the best way in WPF to implement traffic light colours for different status's in the application?

Tags: wpf, colors, status

If an application has a group of status's.
E.g.

- Person Status (Active [green], Inactive[orange], Deceased[red])
- Document Status (Unread[orange], read[green], deleted[red])

As you can tell all that both of these groups of status's use the same colours. 
What do you guys recommend this be implemented in WPF. I am in the process of refactoring and want to make sure that it is reusable, readable and understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each mapping between StatusType (enum?) and color I would implement a ValueConverter from each enum to a brush.

If you want to reuse the colors, create brush resources and assign the resources to the converters.

```
public class PersonStatusToBrushConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WhenActiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WhenActive", typeof(Brush), typeof(PersonStatusToBrushConverter),
            new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Green));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WhenInactiveProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WhenInactive", typeof(Brush), typeof(PersonStatusToBrushConverter),
            new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty WhenDeceasedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WhenDeceased", typeof(Brush), typeof(PersonStatusToBrushConverter),
            new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Red));

    public Brush WhenDeceased
    {
        get { return (Brush) this.GetValue(WhenDeceasedProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(WhenDeceasedProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush WhenInactive
    {
        get { return (Brush) this.GetValue(WhenInactiveProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(WhenInactiveProperty, value); }
    }

    public Brush WhenActive
    {
        get { return (Brush) this.GetValue(WhenActiveProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(WhenActiveProperty, value); }
    }


    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch((PersonStatus)value)
        {
            case PersonStatus.Active:
                return this.WhenActive;
            case PersonStatus.Inactive:
                return this.WhenInactive;
            case PersonStatus.Deceased:
                return this.WhenDeceased;
            default:
                return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For the Document Status I would create a similar converter.

To use this with resources:

```
<UserControl ...
    xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:StatusConverters" >
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GreenBrush" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeBrush" Color="Orange"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedBrush" Color="Red"/>
        <conv:PersonStatusToBrushConverter 
            x:Key="personStatusConverter"
            WhenActive="{StaticResource GreenBrush}" 
            WhenInactive="{StaticResource OrangeBrush}" 
            WhenDeceased="{StaticResource RedBrush}"/>
        <conv:DocumentStatusToBrushConverter 
            x:Key="documentStatusConverter"
            WhenUnread="{StaticResource GreenBrush}" 
            WhenRead="{StaticResource OrangeBrush}" 
            WhenDeleted="{StaticResource RedBrush}"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Ellipse 
         Fill="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource personStatusToBrushConverter}" 
         Width="50" Height="50" />
```

Comment: We do use value converters in a number different places. So it's good to see that this can also be implemented in such way. Thanks for the tip! For the moment I think I will implement it the way you've suggested.